# How to connect database with customview list?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I have created an application with custom view list.But now I want the List to be populated through database.List consists of images also.How can I do that.
Here is the code:

CustomListViewAndroidExample.java

```
  public class CustomListViewAndroidExample extends ActionBarActivity {

        ListView list;
        String[] web = {
                "HealthCareTeam",
                "HealthCareGoals",
                "TestResults",
                "Medication",
                "Exercise",
                "Diet",
                "FindHospitals",
                "Settings"


        } ;

        Integer[] imageId = {
                R.drawable.image0,
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7


        };
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view_android_example);

            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(CustomListViewAndroidExample.this, web, imageId);
             list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
             list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent HealthTeamList= new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this , HealthTeamList.class);
                        startActivity(HealthTeamList);
                        break;
                    case 1 :
                    Intent SimpleListActivity = new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this , SimpleListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(SimpleListActivity);
                    break;
                    case 2 :
                        Intent TestResults = new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this ,TestResults.class);
                        startActivity(TestResults);
                        break;
                    case 3 :
                        Intent Medications= new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this ,Medications.class);
                        startActivity(Medications);
                        break;

                    case 4 :
                        Intent Exercise = new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this ,Exercise.class);
                        startActivity(Exercise);
                        break;

                    case 5 :
                        Intent Diet = new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this , Diet.class);
                        startActivity(Diet);
                        break;
                    case 6 :
                        Intent FindHospital = new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this , Settings.class);
                        startActivity(FindHospital);
                        break;
                    case 7 :
                        Intent hdiwali = new Intent (CustomListViewAndroidExample.this , Settings.class);
                        startActivity(hdiwali);
                        break;
                       };



            }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater()
                    .inflate(R.menu.custom_list_view_android_example, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_custom_list_view_android_example,
                        container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

customList.java

```
 public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        private final Activity context;
         private final String[] web;
         private final Integer[] imageId;
         public CustomList(Activity context,
         String[] web, Integer[] imageId) 
         {
         super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
         this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

         }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
         View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
         TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);

         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
         txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

         imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
         return rowView;
         }
          }

activity_custom_list_view_android_example.xml

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        tools:context=".CustomListViewAndroidExample" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

list_single.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bar_bg"
     android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top" 
   >
  <TableRow>
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"  
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/image"

            />
        </LinearLayout>
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top" 
      >
      <TableRow>      
         <TextView
              android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" 
              android:textSize="16sp" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:layout_span="1"
              /> 
        </TableRow>

      </TableLayout> 

        </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

ManifestFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.customlistview1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.CustomListViewAndroidExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Good_mornig"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.SimpleListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_simple_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.HealthTeamList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_health_team_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Info"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Call"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_call" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Message"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Email1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_email1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Medications"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_medications" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.TestResults"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test_results" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Exercise" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customlistview1.Diet"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_diet" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what are ou facing prolem? and what you want??

Comment: How to populate datas from database as it contains images also.Basically the database connectivity.

Comment: are you using sqlite??

Comment: yes.I have tried something.But facing some issues.Can You Please check this once.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278488/custom-list-view-with-images-and-database-connectivity.Please Help

Comment: do you want to save the image to sqlite?? if you are doing so than you are doing wrong because sqlite can only save 3 data types..intger, string, and text